# Increment a variable and store the value? Python

Tags: python, increment

I'm extremely new at Python.
I'm trying to do a quiz, were you get a point if correct or receive no points if wrong.

```
total_Points = 0

question_1 = input("What is Sweden's biggest island?")
answer1 = "Gotland"


if question_1 == answer1:
    print("Gj, you are correct")

    print("You got" + str(total_Points+int(+1)) + " points")

else :
    print("Wrong")

    print("You still got " + total_Points + " points")

question_2 = input("What country is west of Sweden?")

answer2 = "Norway"

if question_2 == answer2:

    print("Correct!")

    print("Gj, you now have " + str(total_Points+int(+1))+ " points")
else:
    print("Nope, ur wrong")
    print("You still gott" + total_Points + " points")
```

How do you store the value if you got a point in question_1 and also question_2? It should then be 2 points. And what if you answer wrong on the 3rd question? How does it know that you only have 2 points?

Thank you for answering the newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
total_Points = 0

question_1 = input("What is Sweden's biggest island?")
answer1 = "Gotland"


if question_1 == answer1:
    print("Gj, you are correct")
    total_Points = total_Points + 1
    print("You got", total_Points, " points")
else :
    print("Wrong")
    print("You still got ", total_Points, " points")

question_2 = input("What country is west of Sweden?")

answer2 = "Norway"

if question_2 == answer2:

    print("Correct!")
    total_Points = total_Points + 1
    print("Gj, you now have ", total_Points, " points")
else:
    print("Nope, ur wrong")
    print("You still gott", total_Points, " points")
```

As you have declared the variable `total_Points` as 0, so you can add `1` and reassign back to it like `total_Points = total_Points + 1`. So, now, `total_Points` will be having the updated value.

In short you can also increment it's value like `total_Points+=1` also.

Answer (score 0):

```
total_Points = 0

question_1 = input("What is Sweden's biggest island?")
answer1 = "Gotland"


if question_1 == answer1:
    print("Gj, you are correct")
    total_Points += 1
    print("You got" + str(total_Points) + " points")

else :
    print("Wrong")

    print("You still got " + total_Points + " points")

question_2 = input("What country is west of Sweden?")

answer2 = "Norway"

if question_2 == answer2:

    print("Correct!")
    total_Points += 1 
    print("Gj, you now have " + str(total_Points)+ " points")
else:
    print("Nope, ur wrong")
    print("You still gott" + total_Points + " points")
```

You add to the variable `total_Points` which keeps the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
total_Points = 0

question_1 = input("What is Sweden's biggest island?")
answer1 = "Gotland"

if question_1 == answer1:
    print("Gj, you are correct")
    total_Points+=1;

print("You got " + str(total_Points) + " points")
```

will show you the way

Answer (score 0):

Just increment the `total_Points` under all of the correct answer's `if` statement.
For example:

```py
if (correct answer):
    total_Points = total_Points + 1
```